# Sphinx: Overriding the document class

Tags: document-classes, sphinx

I am using `Sphinx` to generate multi-output documents (Epub, HTML, LaTeX). How can I change the use documentclass?

The following snippet should (in my opinion) override the used class but results in

```
% Generated by Sphinx.
\def\sphinxdocclass{scrbook}
\documentclass[,]{sphinxmanual}
```

Here's the code from my `conf.py`:

```
latex_elements = {
     'papersize': '',
     'fontpkg': '',
     'fncychap': '',
     'maketitle': '',
     'pointsize': '',
     'preamble': '',
     'releasename': "",
     'babel': '',
     'printindex': '',
     'fontenc': '',
     'docclass':'scrbook',
     'inputenc': '',
     'classoptions': '',
     'utf8extra': '',
 }
```

The [manual](http://sphinx-doc.org/config.html#latex-options) says, it should not be overridden, since other macros are responsible to set it. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at https://github.com/basespace/basespace-python-sdk/blob/master/doc/latex/sphinxmanual.cls it seems that class just loads the class specified by `\sphinxdocclass` so your generated code looks OK.

Answer (score 7):

This comes very late, but maybe it helps...

I am running sphinx 1.8.2

Do not put the docclass into the *latex_elements* variable dictionary, but put it into the *latex_docclass* dictionary, with key 'howto' and 'manual'. Example code:

```
latex_docclass = {
   'howto': 'yourclass1',
   'manual': 'yourclass2',
}
```

see: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.8/usage/configuration.html#confval-latex_docclass